# Spinner with category and sub-category using SQLite in android

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner, categories

Finally, solved it. This is the code . I just added a method for second spinner on setOnItemSelectedListner of first spinner. Now i can select a value in first spinner and corresponding value will come to second spinner like i have colleges in first spinner and when i select a college in first spinner second spinner will automatically give value corresponding to first spinner

```
 mSpinnerModel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedModel = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected Model: " + selectedModel, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//method for second spinner

       String sp1=String.valueOf(mSpinnerModel.getSelectedItem());
            if(sp1.contentEquals("College1")){
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
               list.add("MAHARANI UNIVERSITY ");
                list.add("MANIPAL ");
                list.add("ITM UNIVERSITY ");
                list.add("UNIVERSITY1");


                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);

                mSpinnerMake.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }
            selectedMake = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            if(sp1.contentEquals("College2")){
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("ITM UNIVERSITY");
                list.add("UNIVERSITY2");
                list.add("UNIVERSITY3");


                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list);
                dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mSpinnerMake.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
            }
            if(sp1.contentEquals("College3")){
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("MANIPAL ");
                list.add("UNIVERSITY4");
                list.add("UNIVERSITY5");


                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list);
                dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                dataAdapter3.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mSpinnerMake.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Try to minimize your example to the part that is necessary for the question to be understood. Furthermore please provide your own attempt and ask a specific question that can be answered. Other people will not do all your work.

Comment: Sorry Jan Henke now it is small code and i have implemented a method inside onItemSelected check out that method. I want to select a item in Spinnermodel as it is category and items will come accordingly in Spinnermake . Now is it feasible to you to understand or do i have elaborate